# Как отправлять одно и тоже сообщение каждые 10 секунд?

Tags: python, telebot, время, таймер

Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия на markup_inline бот писал сообщение с статистикой, через 10 секунд удалял его и отправлял заново, но с изменённой статистикой.

Answer (score 1):

Синхронный подход включает в себя использование модуля `time` с методом `sleep`, если вам необходимо получать только статистику, жертвуя взаимодействием с ботом, то можно сделать вот так.

```
import telebot
import time

TOKEN = 'токен'

# Создание объекта бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Бот начал отправлять сообщения каждые 10 секунд.")
    send_messages_periodically(message.chat.id)

def send_messages_periodically(chat_id):
    counter = 1
    while True:
        message_text = f"Сообщение {counter}"
        
        # Отправляем новое сообщение
        sent_message = bot.send_message(chat_id, message_text)
        
        # Ждем 10 секунд
        time.sleep(10)
        
        # Удаляем предыдущее сообщение
        bot.delete_message(chat_id, sent_message.message_id)
        
        counter += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling()
```

Данный пример показывает работу на основе счётчика, но вы можете вызывать подкорректировать этот пример под собственный функционал.

---

UPD

Асинхронный подход включает в себя использование асинхронных библиотек, таких как `aiogram` вместе с `asyncio`. Данный подход позволяет нам взаимодействовать с командами бота в процессе работы нашего цикла по отправке сообщений.

```
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.utils import executor

API_TOKEN = 'токен'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

counter = 0

send_message_task = None

async def send_periodic_message():
    while True:
        # Отправляем сообщение
        global counter
        counter += 1
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=<ВАШ ЧАТ ID>, text=f"Новое сообщение {counter}")
        # Ждем 10 секунд
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Бот начал отправку сообщений.")
    global send_message_task
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    send_message_task = loop.create_task(send_periodic_message())


@dp.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
async def cmd_stop(message: types.Message):
    # Остановка цикла отправки сообщений
    global send_message_task
    send_message_task.cancel()
    await message.reply("Отправка сообщений остановлена.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Запуск цикла отправки сообщений

    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

В данном коде реализована остановка и запуск процесса отправки сообщений в промежутке 10 секунд. На изображении отражено поведение данного бота. Важным замечанием здесь будет то, что вы используете ваш `chat_id` с ботом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]